# Compiled Golang executable extension for OS X

Tags: linux, macos, go

What extension should I use for Golang executable intended to run on OS X?

As far as I understand it is not important because there are user rights as on Linux which make some file executable, but **what is the convention** if it is not .dmg file, just one executable file, so user knows that it is probably executable?

I don't have OS X. Application is cross-compiled on Linux.

Comment: None. Commands under Unix have no extension.

Comment: Just use `go build` or `go install` on your and go will build the executable like it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention for OSX applications is this: one DMG containing a `.app` executable and a shortcut to `/Applications` for the user to drag to. Since you can't do this, I recommend you provide a download to the `.app` executable directly and instruct users to move it to `/Applications` on your download site.

This is only true for download-it-run-it applications. For applications which are run via the terminal, simply don't use an extension and use a shebang line to tell what application should be executing the file.

Comment: Thank you for reading my question carefully :) and thanks for the answer.